# Jest useContext return value function is not a function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, ts-jest, use-context

I'm new to jest and want to write my first tests, where I want to test a slide change in my swiper. The onClick on my next-slide button has a callback function that comes from a react useContext.

When I run my test, i get this error:

```
SwiperComponent › Swiper slide › renders the name of the next item of my mockData, after clicking next button

    TypeError: trackClickWithParam is not a function

      116 |                         onClick={(event) => {
      117 |                             (event.target as HTMLButtonElement).blur();
    > 118 |                             trackClickWithParam(trackingParamNext);
          |                             ^
      119 |                         }}
```

This is my context:

```
//context
export const TrackingProvider: React.FC = ({ children }) => {
    const [webtrekk, setWebtrekk] = useState<WebTrekk | null>(null);
    const [showCookieConsentLayer, setShowCookieConsentLayer] = useState<boolean>(false);

    const initWebtrekkWithConfig = (config: WebtrekkConfig): void => {
        setWebtrekk(new webtrekkV3(config));
    };

    const trackClickWithParam = (param: string): void => {
        TRACKING_ACTIVE && webtrekk && webtrekk.sendinfo({ linkId: param });
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        TRACKING_ACTIVE && webtrekk && webtrekk.sendinfo();
        window.wt = webtrekk;
    }, [webtrekk]);

    return (
        <TrackingContext.Provider
            value={{
                initWebtrekkWithConfig,
                trackClickWithParam,
                showCookieConsentLayer,
                setShowCookieConsentLayer,
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </TrackingContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

and this is my test:

```
//test
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import SwiperComponent from './SwiperComponent';
import user from '@testing-library/user-event';

const props = {
    onSwiperSlide: jest.fn(),
    currentSwipeLabel: mockData[0].name,
    currentContentItem: mockData[0],
    contentData: mockData,
    contentType: 0,
    trackingParamPrev: '',
    trackingParamNext: '',
};

describe('SwiperComponent', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        render(<SwiperComponent {...props} />);
    });

    it('renders the name of the first item of my mockData', () => {
        const swiperActiveContentName = screen.getByText(mockData[0].name);
        expect(swiperActiveContentName).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

    it('renders the next-slide button', () => {
        const nextSlideButton = screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'Nächster Slide' });
        expect(nextSlideButton).toBeInTheDocument();
    });

    describe('Swiper slide', () => {
        beforeEach(() => {
            user.click(screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'Nächster Slide' }));
        });

        it('renders the name of the next item of my mockData, after clicking next button', () => {
            expect(screen.getByText(mockData[1].name)).toBeInTheDocument();
        });
    });
});
```

Does any1 know why trackClickWithParam shouldn't be a function?
The code doesn't throw any errors outside of my test.
Can I somehow tell the test to ignore the callback?

I'm thankful for any hints =)

Comment: can you add the code of your `SwiperComponent` ? Is SwiperComponent which you are using here to test is it wrapped with your `TrackingProvider` ??

Comment: well, that's it. in my _app.tsx I wrapped everything with the TrackingProvider. It seems like this doesn't count for my test. So I simply added the TrackingProvider in my render method:
`
render(
            <TrackingProvider>
                <SwiperComponent {...props} />
            </TrackingProvider>
        );
`
Thanks mate